# Connecting 2nd Monitor freezes Loki

Tags: release-loki, display

when connecting a 2nd monitor to my Late '08 Macbook Pro running Loki the system instantly slows down so the mouse pointer only moves really choppy  and then freezes.

The 2nd screen is connected via VGA through the default Mini Displayport <-> VGA Adapter.

I've updated to the 4.10 Mainline Kernel, but it didn't help.

Any Ideas?
Thank you so much!

Comment: This is exactly what happens to me
Started yesterday 07/03/17 (Perhaps there was an update)
I have 2 24" screens (DVI and ViewPort) When both are connected, sometimes everything freezes Then if i open the latop lid, its screen becomes the main monitor and everything is working fine, if I close the lid everything freezes again